# WinDbg: what is the address-like in parantheses on first chance exceptions output?

Tags: debugging, windbg

WinDbg Preview breaks just after starting debugging of an executable:

```
(3bf4.2318): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30:
00007ffe`d84e06b0 cc              int     3
```

I will continue:

```
0:000> g
```

It will output a series of **ModLoad:** lines for .NET and OS files, and then similar output about a first chance exception:

```
(3bf4.2318): Unknown exception - code 04242420 (first chance)
```

In the previous output, I understand that code represents the type of exception. But what represents `3bf4.2318`? And why the value is identical to that in the first output that relates to break instruction exception, even though now it states unknown exception?

Comment: This is process id and thread id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the process ID and thread ID where the exception happened. I don't know if that output is described somewhere in the depths of the WinDbg documentation. But you can verify that easily on the initial breakpoint

```
(5130.710): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first chance)
```

and compare that against the [process status (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/---process-status-) (`|`)

```
0:000> |
.  0    id: 5130    create  name: Test.exe
```

and the [thread status (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/---thread-status-) (`~`) which has the same format but without the parens:

```
0:000> ~
.  0  Id: 5130.710 Suspend: 1 Teb: 00c7c000 Unfrozen
```

Process and thread information can be useful, because

a) WinDbg is able to debug many processes simultaneously (e.g. `.childdbg` and `.attach`) and

b) you can use it in the `~~[<Thread ID>]s` command to switch to the thread

```
0:007> ~~[710]s
[...]
0:000>
```